# vc-git doesn't recognize that file is under version control

Tags: git, vc

I initialized a Git repository outside emacs, added and committed the files.

Now if I a file in emacs that is under version control by Git and run `C-x v =` emacs tells me `This file is not under version control`.

It seems emacs missed that I added this file to Git already. How can I tell emacs that this file (and the whole directory) is already in Git, so that I can use the `vc-git-*` commands?

Comment: You're mixing your terminology up. By "open a buffer" do you mean "visit a file" (not already visited) or "switch to a buffer" (of an already-visited file)?

Comment: @phils I edited for clarity, I mean opening a file in emacs (that was already existing and added to Git).

Comment: I can't replicate the problem. Which version of Emacs are you using, on which OS? You might also check whether `M-: (executable-find "git")` knows where your `git` binary lives -- the relevant directory needs to be listed in `C-h v exec-path`.

Comment: Git works without any issues for other files in different project directories, I am using Emacs on OS X in version 24.5.1

Comment: For me, trying to use `C-x v =` on a file not under version control yields "No fileset available here". What is the output of `git diff yourfilename` in a terminal?

Comment: When you say "Git works... for other files..." are you referring to using the `vc` commands in Emacs which are not working for the original case? Git and `vc` are entirely different things. Please take care to be specific in your questions and comments. Can you also verify that when you re-visit the file with `C-x C-v` the problem persists?

Comment: Hm I feel a bit dumb now, but closing the buffer and opening it again fixed the problem, now `vc-` commands work as I would have expected. Sorry for the noise. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emacs caches version control information for each buffer.

If you visit a file first, and then `git add` it in a terminal, Emacs doesn't know this. You can `M-x revert-buffer` to force it to refresh the cache, or kill the buffer and visit the file again.

In the future, you can register such files from within Emacs, using `vc-next-action`, by default bound to `C-x v v`. Though if the file is already registered this command will do something else.

Comment: Instead of `vc-next-action` (which would indeed do something else if the file is already registered), why not `vc-register`?  ( `C-x v i` )

Comment: @T.Verron Thas is indeed a good alternative. I don't recall ever using it, though (it's a bit easier to remember just one key sequence).

Comment: I agree that in a standard workflow (e.g. if the file was just created), `vc-next-action` should be what you want. And anyway, even if it wasn't just created, I guess if the user wants to register the file, he would want to commit it anyway (which should be the result of `vc-next-command` in that case, iirc).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I was a bit confused by the observed behaviour. `C-x v i` sounds like a good thing to remember.

Answer (score 1):

After update of MacOS (10.14.6) I had the same "This file is not under version control" - turns out that I needed to accept xcode license to run git commands.

In terminal just do a `sudo xcodebuild -license`- that fixed my problem.

Comment: Git is Free Software, so you should not need to accept any license to run it.  I recommend you complain to Apple about it.  Also you might like to install Git separately from Xcode, which might avoid the problem.